# Hide elements from WebView with JavaScript ( Android )

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview

I'm trying to remove a banner and the footer from a website I'm loading into a WebView.

**So far my code is working without any issues**

But the the challenge now is when I navigate the website for example opening a link, the banner and footer is displayed for a second until the page is fully loaded. I know I can only manipulate the data after its loaded since I can't access the server of the website I'm loading but I think there has to be a way to get around this issue?

I would be very happy to get some ideas.

Here is my code so far:

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val homeViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root


    return root
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview1)

    fun removeElement(myWebView: WebView ) {

        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('banner').style.display='none';})()")
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName(\"footer\")[0].style.display='none';})()")
     
    }


    myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {


        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            removeElement(view!!)
        }

    }

    myWebView.loadUrl("The URL I'm loading")
    myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack() // Navigate back to previous web page if there is one

        }
        true
    }
    lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
    swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container)
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        myWebView.reload()
        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
    }
    

}
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

- The issue you're facing is due to the asynchronous nature of web page loading. When you navigate to a new page, the JavaScript code to remove the banner and footer is executed only after the new page has finished loading. This results in the banner and footer being displayed for a short period before being hidden.
- Use a WebViewClient that waits for the page to fully load before removing the banner and footer. You can achieve this by extending the WebViewClient class and overriding the onPageFinished method.

  ```
  class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview1)

        fun removeElement(myWebView: WebView) {
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('banner').style.display='none';})()", null)
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName(\"footer\")[0].style.display='none';})()", null)
        }

        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            private var isPageLoaded = false

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                if (!isPageLoaded) {
                    removeElement(view!!)
                    isPageLoaded = true
                }
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                isPageLoaded = false
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
            }
        }

        myWebView.loadUrl("The URL I'm loading")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack() // Navigate back to previous web page if there is one
                isPageLoaded = false
            }
            true
        }

        lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container)
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            myWebView.reload()
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
  }
  ```
- In this code, the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is overridden to intercept link clicks and load them within the same WebView. The removeElement function is called before the new page is loaded, so the banner and footer are removed immediately. This should prevent the banner and footer from being displayed on reload or when navigating.

  ```
  class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview1)

        fun removeElement(myWebView: WebView) {
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('banner').style.display='none';})()", null)
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName(\"footer\")[0].style.display='none';})()", null)
        }

        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            private var isPageLoaded = false

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                if (!isPageLoaded) {
                    removeElement(view!!)
                    isPageLoaded = true
                }
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                isPageLoaded = false
                view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
                removeElement(view)
                return true
            }
        }

        myWebView.loadUrl("The URL I'm loading")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack() // Navigate back to previous web page if there is one
                isPageLoaded = false
            }
            true
        }

        lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container)
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            myWebView.reload()
            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and time, sadly my issue is still there, the banner and footer are still displayed on reload of the page and when navigating.

Comment: @Laviniss Could you review my modified response?

Comment: Again, thanks for your time and patience. The issue now is that the elements ( banner+footer) are even displayed longer than before because of the delay you've added. Maybe we need a different approach to this problem?

Comment: @Laviniss Could you review my modified response?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I tried your new code and it's still the same. The elements are still shown briefly when loading/reloading and navigating the website.